# Angular - Textarea auto height does not automatically resize on text deletion

Tags: angular, dynamic, resize, textarea, refresh

I am using the following directive to allow an auto-sizing to a text area depending on user input:

```
import { ElementRef, HostListener, Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]'
})

export class Autosize implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  onInput(textArea:HTMLTextAreaElement):void {
    this.adjust();
  }

  constructor(public element:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    setTimeout(() => this.adjust(), 0);
  }

  adjust():void {
    const textArea = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
      textArea.style.height = 'auto';
      textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + "px";
      textArea.style.maxHeight = '100px';
  }
}
```

It is working as intended, however when the text inside that textarea is manually deleted, the textarea will not resize automatically.

E.g. if the [(ngModel)] variable assigned to that textarea is assigned a different string, or empty string, the height of the text area will not automatically resize. The user needs to start typing again in order to make the textarea resize accordingly.

What could be a good solution to solving this issue?

Answer (score 13):

I'm using this simple approach, and textarea does shrink when text is deleted :

```
<textarea (keyup)="autoGrowTextZone($event)"></textarea>
```

and

```
autoGrowTextZone(e) {
  e.target.style.height = "0px";
  e.target.style.height = (e.target.scrollHeight + 25)+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You may not need to write your own directive. You can use `cdkTextareaAutosize` from the official Angular CDK.

https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#auto-resizing-code-lt-textarea-gt-code-elements

Comment: This is the best way

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

try adding something like this:

```
ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.adjust();
}
```

or just use this lib: [ngx-autosize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-autosize) :)

**UPDATE**
The solution with ngAfterContentChecked hook is still valid but it might affect app speed if used too often...

another way is to treat ngModel as input and that will let you rely on ngOnChanges hook, so in your directive try adding:

```
...
@Input('ngModel') text: any;
...
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.text) {
        this.adjust();
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying many different methods of achieving this, I found that just using ngx-autosize was the most seamless solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You dont need find textArea, using :

```
this.element.nativeElement.style.height = 'auto';
this.element.nativeElement.style.height = this.element.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
this.element.nativeElement.style.maxHeight = '100px';
```